# Applying several styles to a cell in Excel spreadsheet with AXLSX gem

Tags: ruby, excel, axlsx

I am using the `AXLSX` Ruby gem to generate Excel reports and I'm having a problem applying several styles to cells in a modular way.

Here's an example that has just two styles ("on background" and "bold on background"),

```
require 'axlsx'

axlsx = Axlsx::Package.new
workbook = axlsx.workbook

with_background = workbook.styles.add_style bg_color: "E2D3EB"
bold_with_background = workbook.styles.add_style bg_color: "E2D3EB", b: true

workbook.add_worksheet do |sheet|
  sheet.add_row
  sheet.add_row ["", "Product", "Category", "Price"], style: [0, bold_with_background, bold_with_background, bold_with_background]
  sheet.add_row ["", "Butter", "Dairy", 4.99], style: [0, with_background, with_background, with_background]
  sheet.add_row ["", "Bread", "Baked Goods", 3.45], style: [0, with_background, with_background, with_background]
  sheet.add_row ["", "Broccoli", "Produce", 2.99], style: [0, with_background, with_background, with_background]
end

axlsx.serialize "grocery.xlsx"
```

and here's the result,

[image]

Now, suppose I have to apply a border around this table. If I understand it correctly, I'll have to have a lot of styles to get there: "bold on backbroung with top left edge", "bold on background with top edge", "bold on backgound with top right edge", "on background with right edge", etc.

Is there a way to apply several styles to cells instead of having to declare a style for each possible combination of base styles?

I'd like to have something like

```
sheet["B2"].add_style(bold).add_style(background).add_style(top_left_edge)
```

but not sure if the gem implements a similar solution.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've managed to overlay cell styles by monkey patching `Axlsx` classes. The idea is to first apply raw styles to cell in the form of Ruby hashes. When that is finished one can generate `Axlsx` styles for the workbook and apply them. I can now separate the markup from style, having the styles applied as

```
sheet["B2:D2"].add_style(b: true)
sheet["B2:D5"].add_style(bg_color: "E2D3EB")
workbook.apply_styles
```

Below is the full listing of my hacky solution. This doesn't include identifying unique styles among other things that should be done in professional code. Looking forward to any feedback.

```
require 'axlsx'

class Array
  def add_style(style)
    return unless map{ |e| e.kind_of? Axlsx::Cell }.uniq.first
    each { |cell| cell.add_style(style) }
  end
end

class Axlsx::Workbook
  attr_accessor :styled_cells

  def add_styled_cell(cell)
    self.styled_cells ||= []
    self.styled_cells << cell
  end

  def apply_styles
    return unless styled_cells
    styled_cells.each do |cell|
      cell.style = styles.add_style(cell.raw_style)
    end
  end
end

class Axlsx::Cell
  attr_accessor :raw_style

  def workbook
    row.worksheet.workbook
  end

  def add_style(style)
    self.raw_style ||= {}
    self.raw_style = raw_style.merge(style)
    workbook.add_styled_cell(self)
  end
end

axlsx = Axlsx::Package.new
workbook = axlsx.workbook

workbook.add_worksheet do |sheet|
  sheet.add_row
  sheet.add_row ["", "Product", "Category", "Price"]
  sheet.add_row ["", "Butter", "Dairy", 4.99]
  sheet.add_row ["", "Bread", "Baked Goods", 3.45]
  sheet.add_row ["", "Broccoli", "Produce", 2.99]

  sheet["B2:D2"].add_style(b: true)
  sheet["B2:D5"].add_style(bg_color: "E2D3EB")
end

workbook.apply_styles

axlsx.serialize "grocery.xlsx"
```

**Edit**: I've leaned up my solution and extracted it into a gem https://github.com/sakovias/axlsx_styler

Answer (score 3):

FYI, there is a way to do this using "differential styles". [Look at the docs on styles.rb](https://github.com/randym/axlsx/blob/master/lib/axlsx/stylesheet/styles.rb#L196)

Basically you state your style type is `:dxf`. The default is `:xf`. Everything else is the same. From the link above (title, currency, and percent are normal styles defined earlier):

```
p = Axlsx::Package.new
wb = p.workbook
ws = wb.add_worksheet

# define your styles
profitable = wb.styles.add_style(:bg_color => "FFFF0000",
                           :fg_color=>"#FF000000",
                           :type => :dxf)

ws.add_row ["Genreated At:", Time.now], :styles=>[nil, date_time]
ws.add_row ["Previous Year Quarterly Profits (JPY)"], :style=>title
ws.add_row ["Quarter", "Profit", "% of Total"], :style=>title
ws.add_row ["Q1", 4000, 40], :style=>[title, currency, percent]
ws.add_row ["Q2", 3000, 30], :style=>[title, currency, percent]
ws.add_row ["Q3", 1000, 10], :style=>[title, currency, percent]
ws.add_row ["Q4", 2000, 20], :style=>[title, currency, percent]

ws.add_conditional_formatting("A1:A7", { :type => :cellIs, :operator => :greaterThan, :formula => "2000", :dxfId => profitable, :priority => 1 })
f = File.open('example_differential_styling', 'w')
p.serialize(f)
```

Comment: Thanks @noel! It looks like it's what's I'm looking for. I'll do more digging into the gem's code. I guess I should add an example to the gem at some point as this feature is extremely valuable.